# How to get the id and value from an XML file to a dialog in android

Tags: android, parsing, xml-parsing

This issue has lasted for a week now and i need help, how can I get the value of language type and display the id in dialog, such that its the Language like English, French e.t.c that would be displayed in this dialog, i will be waiting to accept the answer that works.I really dont know how to get this information and display it in a dialog list.

**XML**

```
  <streamlanguage>
      <language_type id="English">
      http://154.obj.netromedia.net/IMMPowered/Aucoms1/playlist.m3u8
      </language_type>
      <language_type id="French">
      http://155.obj.netromedia.net/ipadhigh/Frenchlanx/playlist.m3u8
      </language_type>
      <language_type id="German">
      http://155.obj.netromedia.net/ipadhigh/Germanlanx/playlist.m3u8
      </language_type>
      <language_type id="Russian">
      http://155.obj.netromedia.net/ipadhigh/Russianlanx/playlist.m3u8
      </language_type>
      <language_type id="Arabic">
      http://155.obj.netromedia.net/ipadhigh/Arabiclanx/playlist.m3u8
      </language_type>
       <language_type id="Hindi">
      http://155.obj.netromedia.net/ipadhigh/Hindilanx/playlist.m3u8
      </language_type>
      <language_type id="Portuguese">
      http://155.obj.netromedia.net/ipadhigh/Portulanx/playlist.m3u8
     </language_type>
 </streamlanguage>
```

**Activity**

```
public class Language extends Activity {

   String URL = "";

   static final String KEY_LANG = "streamlanguage";
   static final String KEY_ID = "id";
   static final String KEY_TITLE = "language_type";

   ArrayList<String> menuItems;
   ArrayList<String> menuKeys;


    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.commentlayout);

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("KEY_LANG");

    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("("+parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID)+") "+parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));       
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("language_type");
    for(int x=0,size= nodeList.getLength(); x<size; x++) {
        System.out.println(nodeList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue());
         System.out.println(nodeList.item(x).getTextContent());
    }
```

Comment: @ Amit ok, i will try it now and get back to you

Comment: I have implemented the code you gave, how do i now display the language(ids) in a dialog

Comment: Do you get to value of id

Comment: yes, i am getting it, please can you show me, how i can display the information am getting to a dialog box

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/5810084/android-alertdialog-single-button

Comment: thank you for being there always, i appreciate this. but what i actually need is for you to show me how i can set the data am getting into an this dialog, the dialog should display the list of the languages, in this dialog

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/15762905/how-to-display-list-view-in-alert-dialog-in-android

Comment: sorry, i couldn't implement it immediately but am on it and as soon as it done. i will definitely accept it

Comment: @AmitPrajapati if i want to its url then ?

Comment: @Vaishali  do you please explain what you want to do ?

Comment: try .getTextContent() you get your ans

Comment: i have <media>
 <image id="iamge_a">
 http://www.sfweekly.com/imager/google-headquarters-in-mountain-view/b/original/2657270/6d3a/google_headquarters.jpg
 </image>
 <image id="iamge_b">
 http://cdn.cultofandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Google-building.jpg
 </image>
</media>
this tag and i want to get url of it

Comment: @AmitPrajapati using .getTextContent()  cant able to get url of image so please help me out